Definition of semantic security for all $m_0$ and $m_1$
In this video, at 4:17, the lecturer (Dan Boneh) says that the following definition is "too strong" and cannot be satisfied [with keys shorter than the message]:
def 1:
$\forall m_0, m_1 \text{ such that } |m_0| = |m_1|: \{ E(k, m_0) \} \approx_p \{ E(k, m_1) \} \text{ where } k \stackrel{R}{\gets} K$
Here, $\approx_p$ denotes computational indistinguishability.
By expanding $\approx_p$ we get:
Def 1':
$\forall m_0, m_1 \text{ such that } |m_0| = |m_1|: \forall \mathcal A \text{ – polynomial algorithm}:\\ |\Pr_{k \gets K}[\mathcal A(E(k, m_0)) = 1] - \Pr_{k \gets K}[\mathcal A(E(k, m_1)) = 1]| \le \epsilon \text{ where } \epsilon \text{ is negligible}$
So, he says that we need to add an extra requirement that $m_0$ and $m_1$ can be explicitly exhibited by a polynomial attacker. I believe that it can be written formally as follows:
def 2:
$\forall (\mathcal A_0, \mathcal A_1) \text{ – polynomial algorithms}: \text{ let } (m_0, m_1) = \mathcal A_0(), \text{ then }:\\
|\Pr_{k \gets K}[\mathcal A_1(E(k, m_0)) = 1] - \Pr_{k \gets K}[\mathcal A_1(E(k, m_1)) = 1]| \le \epsilon \text{ where } \epsilon \text{ is negligible}$
Now, to me, these 2 definitions appear identical as it is clear that for any $m_0$ and $m_1$ there is a trivial polynomial algorithm that simply outputs them.
At first, I thought that this was simply a mistake in the video, but the same definition seems to be repeated in the textbook by Boneh & Shoup, although skipping over def 1.
I also cannot find any source that would define semantic security as in def 1.
Am I missing something? Is def 1 a valid, equivalent, definition of semantic security? If not, is there an example to see why it's different.
UPD 1: I guess I can see how the phrase "explicitly exhibited by a polynomial attacker" can be meaningfully interpreted, akin to the definition of collision resistance for hash functions (considering a family of functions $E_{k'}(k, m)$ instead of a single function $E(k, m)$). However, I don't think it should be interpreted that way as it would be quite different from the traditional game-based definition of semantic security, which still appears to me to be equivalent to def 1.
UPD 2: In fact, for stream ciphers, the choice of $m_0$ and $m_1$ is completely irrelevant as the message is simply XORed with the PRG output. The adversary might as well request encryptions of all 0s and XOR $m_0$ and $m_1$ in itself. So, it appears to me, any stream cipher secure under any reasonable definition would be secure under def 1.

I think, Dan Boneh means the probabilistic polynomial time adversary should be able to  find/present two messages such that can be considered as a test for our cryptosystem. i.e., we consider realistic situations, rather than mathematical case of literally all $m_0,m_1\in\mathcal{M}$. (Look at page 17 after equation (2.4) of the book)

The problem is that for any $m_0$, $m_1$, there is a probabilistic polynomial time adversary that can present them (just have them hard-coded). So, my claim is that def 1 from my question is equivalent to the final definition in the book & the video.

You can imagine a cipher $E$ such that we know that it doesn't work for some messages, no-one just knows what those messages are, like the way we know that there exist sha-256 collisions, but no-one just knows what they are. However, as far as I can see, this intuition is not captured by any of the presented definitions.

The adversary you are describing (which hard-codes the values of $m_0$ and $m_1$) is a non-uniform adversary. The size of the keys and messages depends on a security parameter. Def 1 would be security against non-uniform adversaries and def 2 against uniform adversaries. I don't know if this is the reason why Boneh says it is too strong, but it could be one reason. Security is typically harder to prove vs non-uniform adversaries.

If we interpret $m_0,m_1$ as fixed strings that do not depend on the "security parameter", then def 1 and def 2 are equivalent (by your argument) if we consider the adversaries to be uniform polynomial algorithms or if we consider them to be nonuniform polynomial adversaries. However, this definition is too weak.
The "correct" interprepretation to not be too weak is that $m_0,m_1$ should be  interpreted as a sequence of message pairs (one for each value of the security parameter, with lengths bounded by a polynomial in the security parameter). In this case, as lamontap noted, your argument still works to show that they are equivalent if we consider nonuniform polynomial adversaries, but does not work if we consider uniform polynomial adversaries.
That said, Dan's claim that the definition "still cannot be satisfied" is too strong of a statement. To the best of our knowledge, nonuniform security is achievable. (Indeed, many people would likely conjecture that anything which is asymptotically secure again uniform attacks is also secure against nonuniform attacks,) On the other hand there are good reasons (both practical and theoretical) to prefer to work with "uniform" definitions.

On the practical side, there are good reasons to believe that uniform security does a better job at estimating the "concrete" security of real world schemes (see e.g. http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/359 and https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/318).
On the theoretical side, uniform proofs of security tend to be trivially modifiable to become non-uniform proofs of security (by just swapping "uniform" with "non-uniform" everywhere it appears), whereas a proof of security regarding non-uniform security may require more effort to become a uniform proof.

Regarding "UPD 2", your argument works iff the attacker knows what the messages are. But in the case of def 1 with a uniform attacker, the attacker would not be able to know that.
